# PtIJ: why a twisted 6

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In many of the cloth uses of the mishkan  it says that you should use שש משזר "a twisted 6". What is this? A 9 perhaps? What's the special significance of a twisted 6 and not just a 9?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this refers to what is commonly known as a 9.  However, as noted in [my answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4518/16354) to [PTIJ: Worst post contest: 5778](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4509/ptij-worst-post-contest-5778), the Torah cannot mention nine, due to the known Maamar:

> Why was six afraid of seven?  Because seven ate nine!
>
> (למה שש פחדה משבע? כי שבע אכל תשע! (תרגום שלי

Answer (score 2):

A twisted 6 is actually an 8, not a 9, as the some of the other answers have suggested. It's pretty simple to see that. Just extend the top of the 6 and twist it around until it meets the bottom.

A twisted 8 is extremely useful when making a [stein knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure-eight_knot) which is a form of a figure 8 (or twisted 6) knot. Wikipedia says:

> It is used to secure a rope that is already passed around a post or
>   through a ring. It is quick and easy to tie and untie. It is a device
>   rigging rather than a true knot.

The curtains of the *mishkan* were fastened to rods, so, it made sense to shape them as 8's or twisted sixes.

Answer (score 0):

It's an allusion to the third temple.

Ok, let me explain.  First, it's a six, which is two threes, one for each temple we've already had.  We know that a cord of three strands is not easily broken, and that [R' Yochanan says the third strand is Hashem](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89270/472), Who is the reason we built the *mishkan* and temples at all.  So "three" connects Yisrael to Hashem.

But *sheish*, six, tells us that three wouldn't be enough, and that we'd need to do it again -- two temples, so six cords.

But as [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89464/472) says, six really means nine.  Which is three sets of three, so the two temples of the past and the one yet to come.

And that one will endure, because a cord of three cords of three surely cannot be broken.