# PTIJ: Who was the sixth set of priestly clothes for?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

We read in [Parshat Pekudei 40:27-28](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.39.27?lang=bi):

> וַֽיַּעֲשׂ֛וּ אֶת־הַכָּתְנֹ֥ת שֵׁ֖שׁ מַעֲשֵׂ֣ה אֹרֵ֑ג לְאַהֲרֹ֖ן וּלְבָנָֽיו׃ וְאֵת֙ הַמִּצְנֶ֣פֶת שֵׁ֔שׁ וְאֶת־פַּאֲרֵ֥י הַמִּגְבָּעֹ֖ת שֵׁ֑שׁ וְאֶת־מִכְנְסֵ֥י הַבָּ֖ד שֵׁ֥שׁ
>
> They made the six tunics of woven work, for Aharon and his sons; and the six headdresses, and the six decorated turbans, and the six pairs of linen breeches.

By my count, they only needed five sets of *bigdei kehuna* - for Aharon and his four sons: Nadav, Avihu, Elazar and Itamar.

For whom was the sixth set of *bigdei kehuna* made?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Remember the footer

Comment: similar PT https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89458/16354

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The verse that you quoted says that these six sets were "for Aaron and his sons". In fact Moses needed a set, for, as we know, he served as priest for the week that the tabernacle was being inaugurated. That's the sixth set. Why does it call him Aaron's son? As Rashi (Numbers 3:1) explains:

> שכל המלמד את בן חברו תורה מעלה עליו הכתוב כאילו ילדו
>
> whoever teaches his friend's son Torah, it's as if he fathered him.

Since Moses taught Aaron's son Torah, it's as if Aaron fathered Moses.